# Second monitor turns to black after loading OS

Tags: gnome, xorg, multiple-monitors, desktop-environments

I have a Gnome Ubuntu 16.04 system with 3 monitors, two connected to an nvidia card and the third to an integrated Intel GPU.

Today my third monitor suddenly stopped working after loading the OS/DE: I can see the gnome loading bar on it while it loads the OS, but as soon as the login screen shows it gets black and stays black. It doesn't say "No video input" or something, just black. If I use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to open the login shell, it opens on said third monitor as well. Does this mean the desktop environment/gnome has issues with that monitor? Or is is possible that an nvidia problem is causing this, although it isn't even connected to the nvidia card? It also works fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 Unity laptop.

I've tried `xrandr -q`, and it doesn't show up there. Are there any other commands that might be useful to investigate?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: On grub boot-up menu select **Advanced Options** and try booting with previous kernel to see if that brings life back to third monitor.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sadly not, still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing a different nvidia driver.
Apparently there is an issue with 384.111, because after reinstalling that one the problem appears again. Specifically, I went to 387.34, although 384 is the long-term branch.